# HA a SQL database, combine failover cluster with AlwaysOn?

Tags: sql-server, biztalk, high-availability

We have a BizTalk setup, its databases are setup on a failover cluster to achieve the HA (High Availability). Client have an application database that also needs to achieve the HA, usually I'd suggest to put on the same instance with BizTalk database but client DBA insists to use the AlwaysOn feature.

BizTalk Server does not support the alwayson due to some DTC complications, having said that, is it possible to enable the AlwaysOn feature on the same SQL Server to satisfy the customer needs while not disturbing the DTC requirement by BizTalk? Or it simply has to be two sets of SQL Server deployment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Always On feature does not support MSDTC, BizTalk does not support Always On since it relies on MSDTC. See link [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj248703(v=bts.80).aspx) link (at the bottom of page). Your other database for which you need always on, put it on a separate SQL instance. It may share the same cluster node as BizTalk server SQL instance.